# How to create MockRepository for generic repository

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I am new to TDD pattern so I want to create basic demo Application in Asp.Net MVC which has a generic repository. Can anyone tell me how to create a generic mock using mockrepository for unit testing?

My generic repository code is as follow

```
public class PoolManagementRepository<T> :IPoolManagementRepository<T> where T:class
{

   internal PoolManagmentEntities context;
    internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public PoolManagementRepository(PoolManagmentEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    #region Reository Operation

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
       return context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual T GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        T entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entityToDelete)
    {

    }

    public virtual void Update(T entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What did you try? How far did you get? Where are you struggeling?

Comment: I create generic repository but I want to create MockRepository which would be generic  for TDD can you please tell me how to achieve it.

Comment: I am facing issue at generic FindById method of List

Comment: In TDD (Test Driven Development) you write the tests first, and then the code to pass the tests. Where are your tests?

Comment: I am trying to create my tests for generic  repository by using generic mock repository,Actually I am new to TDD hence I wrote code first

Comment: This is the top result for "mockrepository generic" on Google, but has no answers. It's frustrating to say the least.

Comment: @john ask a new question if you are not finding it. Maybe the community will help.

Comment: @Nkosi To be honest, I'll probably answer this one when I find the answer. I would ask a new one, but this _is_ the top result on Google as I said, so it would probably be best to answer this one for the purposes of searchability.

Comment: @john while I would tend to agree with the searchability, the question is unclear, too broad and incomplete IMO. But I totally get your point.

Comment: I would suggest only supplying a mock repository with the specific method required by the class/method under test. Start small and grow your system guided by tests.